# Find different chars in strings and save their index and how they changed

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

Ok, so i have DataFrame Col named DNA with long strings like 3k in len, and i have my reference string. Everything's the same length. I need to compare each char in each string to this refrence string and if chars are diffrent save them to a list in a way

[**refrence char**, **position**, **different char**]

letter B       on position 4     changed to C

and I need to create that list for every different char then i need to add each list one big list and this one big list of lists to new col in appropriate row

**visualization**

```
refrence string = 'AXBCSEQHS'

     DNA             WHAT CHANGED
'AABCDEQHS', [['X', 1, 'A'], ['S', 4, 'D']]
'LAPEDEQHS', [['A', 0, 'L'], ['X', 1, 'A'], ['B', 2, 'P'], ['C', 3, 'E'], ['S', 4, 'D']]
```

What i did is a small Proof of concept in clean python just to help you understand

```py
list_str = ['LAPEDEXHS']
ctr_str = 'AXBCSEQHS'
w = []

for x in list_str:
    for y in range(len(ctr_str)):
        if x[y] == ctr_str[y]:
            pass
        else:
            c = [ctr_str[y], y, x[y]]
            w.append(c)
print(w)
```

I was searching around stack to find something similar but i didn't find anything that was helpful
I can do that in plain python but i have 150 cols filled with string that are 3k chars long so i don't think plain python will cut it

Comment: have you tried doing it in plain python? 3000 chars times 150 columns should be just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, with your own code, it will be more efficient.

```
list_str = ['AABCDEQHS'* 300, 'LAPEDEXHS'* 300] * 1000
ctr_str = 'AXBCSEQHS'* 300
w_all = []

for x in list_str:
    w = []
    for y in range(len(ctr_str)):
        if x[y] == ctr_str[y]:
            pass
        else:
            c = [ctr_str[y], y, x[y]]
            w.append(c)
            
    w_all.append(w)
```

define a function:

```
def get_changed(x, ctr_str):
    w = []
    for y in range(len(ctr_str)):
        if x[y] == ctr_str[y]:
            continue
        else:
            c = [ctr_str[y], y, x[y]]
            w.append(c)
    return w
what_changed = df['DNA'].map(lambda x: get_changed(x, ctr_str))
```

---

step1: create two dataframe to store list_str and ctr_str, as every char as a column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_str = ['AABCDEQHS', 'LAPEDEXHS']
ctr_str = 'AXBCSEQHS'

df_list = pd.DataFrame(map(list,list_str))
ctr_values = np.array([list(ctr_str)])
df_ctr = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(ctr_values, df_list.shape[0], axis=0))

print(df_list)

       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    0  A  A  B  C  D  E  Q  H  S
    1  L  A  P  E  D  E  X  H  S

print(df_ctr)

       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
    0  A  X  B  C  S  E  Q  H  S
    1  A  X  B  C  S  E  Q  H  S
```

step2: compare df_ctr and df_list, to find which cell is not same. then join df_ctr and df_list's cell. and stack.

```
cond = df_ctr != df_list
df = (df_ctr[cond] + df_list[cond])
df = df.stack().map(list).reset_index(name='paris')
print(df)

       level_0  level_1   paris
    0        0        1  [X, A]
    1        0        4  [S, D]
    2        1        0  [A, L]
    3        1        1  [X, A]
    4        1        2  [B, P]
    5        1        3  [C, E]
    6        1        4  [S, D]
    7        1        6  [Q, X]
```

step3: merge the change char and it's index

```
obj = df.set_index('level_0').apply(lambda x: [x['paris'][0], x['level_1'], x['paris'][1]], axis =1)
print(obj)

    level_0
    0    [X, 1, A]
    0    [S, 4, D]
    1    [A, 0, L]
    1    [X, 1, A]
    1    [B, 2, P]
    1    [C, 3, E]
    1    [S, 4, D]
    1    [Q, 6, X]
    dtype: object
```

step4: merge to list with same index

```
obj = obj.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
print(obj)

    level_0
    0                               [[X, 1, A], [S, 4, D]]
    1    [[A, 0, L], [X, 1, A], [B, 2, P], [C, 3, E], [...
    dtype: object
```

step5: get result

```
df_result = obj.reset_index()
df_result.columns = ['DNA', 'WHAT CHANGED']
df_result['DNA'] = df_result['DNA'].replace(dict(enumerate(list_str)))
print(df_result)


             DNA                                       WHAT CHANGED
    0  AABCDEQHS                             [[X, 1, A], [S, 4, D]]
    1  LAPEDEXHS  [[A, 0, L], [X, 1, A], [B, 2, P], [C, 3, E], [...
```